# How to apply javascript formatting to .json files?

Tags: json, eclipse, formatting, indentation, auto-indent

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> hotkey in Eclipse can format a file. It doesn't work for `.json` files. How to make it work?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You'll want to get the JSON Editor plugin if you don't already have it. You can find it [here](http://eclipsejsonedit.sourceforge.net/)

> The JSON Editor is a simple plugin for the Eclipse IDE that provides: - Color text highlighting - An Outline Tree view - JSON validation - Text formatting - Text folding for the JSON data format.

If the hot keys still don't work. Take a look under the menu as shown in the picture from their site [here](http://sourceforge.net/dbimage.php?id=217754)

Also, I see that there has been at least one issue with what looks to be the current versions formatting feature in the past.
From their discussion [site:](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsejsonedit/forums/forum/957258/topic/3771450)

```
rlespinola 
2010-07-15 00:18:05 UTC
Using version 0.9.4, I do not see the option to "Format Text". Also, when I open a .json file, the outline view says "An outline is not available".

jdschulteis
2010-12-27 16:59:24 UTC
Using 0.9.4 on Helios, I also had "An outline is not available". I went to Window->Preferences->General->Editors->File Associations, selected '*.json' in the 'File types:' list, selected 'Json Editor' in the 'Associated editors:' list, and clicked 'Default'. I now get an outline, though it can be somewhat slow (6K line file).
```

**Edit:**

There are several ways to add a plugin.  Eclipse recommends using the [update manager](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_install_new_plug-ins%3F). 
Try [help > software updates > find and install](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-34.htm)

You can look [here](http://www.venukb.com/2006/08/20/install-eclipse-plugins-the-easy-way/) for some alternative methods.

Comment: I couldn't find install instructions. When I click "Help > Install New Software > Add repository > From archive" on Helios it doesn't work

Comment: Which link are you referring to? All the links worked for me. However, probably the easiest way to install the plugin is to use the eclipse marketplace (Help->Eclipse Marketplace on Juno), and search for "JSON Editor Plugin". It takes a while to install but it works.

Comment: @OldWolf How to format the `json` received from the above plugin, I used ,<kbd> ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> , it formats the output but whole the code is in black and white. It is very difficult with out colours. How to fix this

Answer (score 5):

There are two options I figured out using Eclipse Luna (4.4.0).

**Use a JSON Editor Plugin and define shortcuts**

- Download and install the JSON Editor Plugin from sourceforge manually or use the Eclipse marketplace (Help -> Eclipse marketplace) to find and install the plugin
- Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys and filter for "format text".
- Choose "Format Text" and set the "When:" value to "Editing Text" (sadly there is no explicit condition for JSON editing, but the format event for the JSON Editor is different to the other editors, so "Editing Text" will work aswell)
- Set the "Binding:" to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>

**Use the Javascript Development Plugin with an ugly and anoying workaround**

- Get the plugin using Help -> Install New Software -> Work with: "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" -> Programming Languages -> JavaScript Development Tools
- Associate *.json files with the  JavaScript Editor (Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations)
- You can now create files with "json" extension and edit them in Eclipse using the JavaScript Editor, but formatting with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will not work directly with the following unformatted example:

```js
{"addressbook": {"name": "John Doe",

    "address": {

        "street": "5 Main Street", "city": "San Diego, CA", "zip": 91912
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        "619 555-3452",
        "664 555-4667"
    ]
 }
}
```

- The hack is to create a valid JavaScript variable from the object description like this:

```js
var obj =    {"addressbook": {"name": "John Doe",

    "address": {

        "street": "5 Main Street", "city": "San Diego, CA", "zip": 91912
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        "619 555-3452",
        "664 555-4667"
    ]
 }
}
```

- Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> will now work
- In the end you will have to remove the "var obj =" hack to make the JSON file valid again

Comment: This is perfectly useful, especially due to this tip: `Choose "Format Text" and set the "When:" value to "Editing Text"`

Answer (score 4):

You could use the JavaScript editor that ships with Eclipse.

Comment: If you just need syntax highlighting and auto-formatting, the default JavaScript editor works fine.

Comment: Um, yes...that's what I said. Why this comment?

Comment: The JSON editor plugin the other answer mentions also supports text folding and provides an outline tree view. The default editor does not. I just wanted to make this difference clear.

Comment: This works better if your JSON has (illegal, but whatever) comments in it. The JSON Editor plugin mangles them.

Comment: The original question was about using Ctrl-Shift-F (or Source->Format) to format a .json document, and the JSON Editor Plugin supports this, while the eclipse JS editor does not.